# Typescript expression with nullcheck is possibly undefined but only in Angular template

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following code:

ts:

```
  get myArray(): any[]{
    return [1,2,3];
  }
```

template:

```
<p>Test:</p>
<div *ngIf="myArray?.length > 2">
  array has more than 2 items
</div>
```

For this, the compiler tells me:

```
Error in src/app/app.component.html (2:13)
Object is possibly 'undefined'.
```

Why? The code works just fine, if I write the exact same expression in the component:

```
  constructor(){
    if(this.myArray?.length > 2){
      console.log("yay")
    }
  }
```

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hhpoag?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "strict": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

Comment: It's looks like in .html (in strict mode) don't allow compare a null or undefined with a number, you can use `*ngIf="myArray && myArray.length>2"`.NOTE: works the `*ngIf mtArray?.length` because this say "if exist and not empty"

Comment: Not sure why it behaves differently, but in template `?.` makes typeof `myArray?.length` to be `number | undefined`. In component `?`  makes no difference because return type can't be nullish (`any[]`).

Comment: Remove the `?` from `*ngIf="myArray?.length > 2"`?

Comment: Why do you need `?.` for always defined value?

Comment: Angular template takes no chances. As well with async pipe and observables - you won't be allowed to compare the outcome to a number in < or > way, because the optional undefined or null.

@Eliseo comment is probably the best option.

Comment: cheers for the help! @AlekseyL. seems you found the source of the error too.  (regarding the "why the nullsafe operator": its a more complex expression in my code, where it's required to have it, but you are right, avoiding it also fixes the issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my collegues pointed out the source of the error:

The Angular Template Engine (probably) overcasts the type of my getter. The `myArray` type will change from `any[]` to `any[] | undefined`. If we do that the typescript code in the component will fail also:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: ``
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  get myArray(): any[] | undefined {    // causes build time error too without a template
    return [1,2,3];
  }

  constructor(){
    if(this.myArray?.length > 2){
      console.log("yay")
    }
  }
}
```

One possible solution is to check the value and replace it if needed, like this in the template:

```
<p>Test:</p>
<div *ngIf="(myArray?.length ?? 0) > 2">
  array has more than 2 items
</div>
```

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-muwdqu?file=src/app/app.component.html